# Is there a way to import common feature file to another feature file in cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, regression, e2e-testing, regression-testing

Is there a way to import one cucumber feature file to another? so that I can move my repeated logics/actions/business validations for different flow to a common feature file.

Note: am using the background option effectively for few things like launching the application in every feature file. if consider it, even that background is also duplicated. :)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to include one feature file in another.

If you could, then Gherkin could be considered to be a programming language. Gherkin isn't a programming language and thus lacks features like functions or modules.

What can you do about your repeated backgrounds then? My approach would probably be to see if I could move the common initialization you do in the background down the stack. I would see if I could implement some helpers that would perform the same steps and then either minimize the background to something like

```
Given the world is prepared
```

in a background. Or just make sure that the preparation was done first in the scenarios that needed it. Maybe even hide it so the call is done in the first step. This would essentially move the background away from the feature file and hide it from for your business stakeholders.

One thing to consider tho would be, is the background important for your business stakeholders? Do they care about the backgrounds or is it just noise for them? If it is important, then don't hide the backgrounds. If the backgrounds isn't important, then hide them as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with this by abstraction and background.

Given any number of prerequisites, if you group them together and give them a name you can call them in one step. In the cucumber space its far more effective to do this rather than import.

BDD is all about working at different levels of abstraction. In particular when you create some specific behaviour you work at a detailed level. Once the behaviour is created you then use that behaviour in a more abstract way.

Importing just gives you access to the detail. This is a bad thing because you end up working with different levels of abstraction in the same place which is both dangerous and confusing.